# how to send USSD command through kannel

Tags: sms-gateway, kannel, ussd

I want to send a USSD command through kannel like this *222#. As for sending sms I usually put this command to my browser localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?smsc=ufone&username=kannel&password=kannel&to=12126555764&text=test+message but I want to send ussd command like this *222# so please help me how to that

Comment: in kannel.conf I did this

group = modems
id = teltonika
name = "Teltonika E12"
detect-string = "Undefined"
enable-mms = true
init-string = "AT+CNMI=2,2,0,1,1"
speed = 115200

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send any sms using kannel use curl "here your whole url with all required params"

If you want to make ussd application you need to have network (ufone/telenor) smpp details of smsc, then you need to install a kannel, create ussd RestAPI.

Then you will be able to send ussd.